# Service worker: check cached resources are up-to-date or latest

Tags: caching, service-worker

I've sw.js code like:

```
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open('cache').then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/',
        '/index.html',
        '/styles/main.css',
        '/scripts/main.min.js'
      ])
      .then(() => self.skipWaiting());
    })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('activate',  event => {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

I've updated the *index.html* file recently, but the file isn't reflected the site. It's still showing the old content of index.html.

Now, How can I make sure app will be serving the latest code if file's changed on the server?

I've been seeing some related answers (like update and refresh), but please tell me what's going on each part of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Switch from your current [cache-first](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#cache-falling-back-to-network) strategy in your `fetch` handler to a strategy like [stale-while-revalidate](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#stale-while-revalidate).
2. Use a build-time tool to generate a service worker that changes each time one of your local resources changes, which will trigger the `install` and `activate` handlers, giving them a chance to update your users' caches with the latest copies of your assets. These tools work by generating hashes of each local file and inlining those hashes into the generated service worker script.

Option 2. is more efficient, because your users will only have to make requests for your assets when something actually changes, as opposed to when using a stale-while-revalidate strategy, which requires firing off a "revalidate" request in the background each time your `fetch` handler is invoked. Option 2. does require a bit more work, though, because you need to incorporate a step into your build process to generate your service worker for you.

If you go the option 2. route, there are a few different build tools that I know about:

- [`sw-precache`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#wrappers-and-starter-kits) (disclosure: I'm the author)
- [`offline-plugin`](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin)

Comment: I'm using gulp as the build tool now. Will try to implement the same. I understood that I needed to let SW know that I changed the resources. But in that case, I suppose I needed to remove the index.html from caching, since If I cache `index.html` SW couldn't know that I changed the resources, right?

Comment: You can serve `index.html` cache-first using a SW, and using a tool like `sw-precache`, it will be automatically updated in the background when any changes are detected—including changes to the `src`/`href` for subresources. Then, the next time the user visits `index.html`, they'll see the updated resources. There's a `gulp` example at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/tree/master/demo